# Using jenkins pipeline agent label based on parameter value choice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have this example pipeline(part of it):

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'myParam', choices: ['1','2'], description: 'param desc')
    }
    options { timestamps () }
    agent {
        node {
            label 'myLabel'
        }
    }
```

my question is this:

I would like to change myLabel for my agent label based on users choice of myParam.
in this case i want that when myParam is 1 then myLabel would be equal to "linux_first" and when myParam is 2 then myLabel would be "linux_second".

Does anyone know a way to do it?
Thanks in advance,
Alon

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar need and I solved it by making the parameter to be the label itself:

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        choice(
            name: 'myParam',
            choices: ['linux_first','linux_second'],
            description: 'param desc'
        )
    }
    options { timestamps() }
    agent { label "${params.myParam}" }
    stages {
        stage('Greeting') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello from ${env.NODE_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to keep your `choices: ['1','2']` then it's more complicated and involves a piece of scripted pipeline in a separate stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'myParam', choices: ['1','2'], description: 'param desc')
    }
    options { timestamps() }
    stages {
        stage('Configure') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.myParam == '1') {
                        MY_AGENT_LABEL = 'linux_first'
                    } else {
                        MY_AGENT_LABEL = 'linux_second'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Greeting') {
            agent { label "${MY_AGENT_LABEL}" }
            steps {
                echo "Hello from ${env.NODE_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar need and I wanted to offer a slightly more flexible option here. You can use string interpolation of raw parameter values in labels but you can also use inline conditionals or a function call so that you can have as much control as you want.

Example w/ conditional:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'label' + (params.myParam == 'option one' ? '_1' : '_2')
        }
    }
...
```

Example w/ function call:

```
String get_agent_label(String input_param) {
    if (input_param == 'option one') {
        return 'label_1'
    } else if (input_param == 'option two') {
        return 'label_2'
    }
    return 'label_default'
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label get_agent_label(params.myParam)
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1-

You can try "nodeLabelParameter" plugin. It might help you based on your requirement.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter/

This plugin adds two new parameter types to job configuration - node and label. The new parameters allow dynamic selection of the node or label where a job should be executed.

Approach 2-

Also Basic syntax would be to define parameter for pipeline and consume it.

```
agent {
label "${build_agent}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize the agent this way in the declarative pipeline

```
properties([
   string(description: 'build Agent', name: 'build_agent')
])

pipeline {
   agent {
      label params['build_agent']
   }
   stages {
      // steps 
   }
}
```